# How to extract first part of a file name?

Tags: python

Newbie to Python here. I've been trying to iterate through filenames in a loop and grab the first part of the file name with Python.

My file names are structured as such: `"Pitt_0050003_rest.nii.gz"`. I only want the `"Pitt_0050003"` part (keep in mind, the file names are various lengths).

Here's the code I've been trying:

```
fileid = []
for f in dataset:
    #print(f)
    comp=f.split('/')
    fs = (comp[-1]) #get the file name without nii.gz extension
    res = re.findall("_rest.nii(\d-)", f) #get the file name without _rest?
    if not res: continue
    fileid.append(res)
print (fileid)
```

Any tips?

Comment: You are nearly there with it. If you do `res = re.match("(.*)_rest\.nii\.gz", f)` you should then be able to get the stem as `res.group(1)`. The first (and only) group corresponds to what is matched by the pattern inside the first (and only) set of brackets - the `.*` that matches everything before the `_rest` etc.

Comment: By the way, for the filename part, yes you can use `f.split('/')[-1]` but see also `os.path.basename(f)`

Comment: Good first post! :) My only suggestion on this post is it is usually good to specify what version of python you are using with your question. It can help the community give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

If all you files will have a '_rest' at the end, then you can try this:

```
string = "Pitt_0050003_rest.nii.gz."
string = string[:string.index('_rest')]
# Value of string from this line will be Pitt_0050003
```

Comment: I'd suggest `index` over `find` here (or just `split`/`rsplit`/`partition`/`rpartition` family); if your assumption about file names is wrong, `find` will return `-1` silently, which will just slice off the last character of the string no matter what it was without informing you. `index` will raise an exception, so you don't misbehave silently.

Comment: Yea, your right. But I think OP wants to remove the '_rest' part. And I think that giving a answer that he is able to grasp easily is better than telling him to use functions when he might not have any idea about.

Comment: `index` is exactly the same usage as `find` here, not sure why you think it's more complicated...

Comment: Yea,Sorry I forgot to edit it. I meant the 'complicated stuff' for split and partition, as I found it was a bit more complicated when i started out in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can split by underscore and ignore the last index if your naming convention remains same for all varying filenames.

```
> myfile = "Pitt_0050003_rest.nii.gz"
> first_name = myfile.split('_')
> first_name
['Pitt', '0050003', 'rest.nii.gz']
> first_name.pop()
'rest.nii.gz'
> 
> first_name
['Pitt', '0050003']
> 
> '_'.join(first_name)
'Pitt_0050003'
>
```